# Average path length in tries from the root to the left most leaf

Tags: algorithms, trees, binary, average

Dear StackExchange Community,

During my preparations for an exam on the "analysis of algorithms" I have encountered a question, that I have not been able to answer.
The task is to determine the average path length in tries from the root to the left most leaf.
Note that the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Bitwise_tries) does not exactly match the version of tries that we used in the [lecture](https://owncloud.tuwien.ac.at/index.php/s/VMiDPcYa4vxpqJU).

In the latter definition, tries are binary trees with a root, where data points are stored in the leaf nodes and each data point gets assigned a unique $0$-$1$-sequence as a key.
When selecting a data point, one starts at the root and goes down left or right in the $n$-th step, according to whether the $n$-th digit of the data point's key sequence is a $0$ or $1$ respectively.

The probabilistic model that we used to analyse certain properties of tries generates independent $0$-$1$-sequences, where the random variables for the digits are also independent and uniform on $\{ 0, 1 \}$.

So far, I have tried to calculate the probability that a trie with $n$ data points has path length $k$ from the root to the left most leaf node.
I think  that the following should suffice:

\begin{align}
    P(0^k || \ast ~ \text{and} ~ 0^{k-1} 1 || \ast ~ \text{are keys, but} ~ 0^{k+1} || \ast ~ \text{is not.}) 
\end{align}

Another approach that I have thought about was using generating functions where I mark the left most nodes. 
Unfortunately, I have not succeeded in fully carrying out any of these two approaches. Maybe someone is technically more skilled and can give me a hint on executing the above or has a more elegant approach. In any case, I would be glad to hear of it.